# Erro no sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

No sql como faço para fazer um select com espaço e sem espaços?

Isto é, quando tenho uma pass do gênero '123456' e '123456 ', o último com espaço acontece que se fizer na query e tenho '123456 ' na bd não me devia mostrar campo nenhum visto que tem um espaço e o meu parâmetro é '123456'

slq password= '&%$#"!'  é esta a pass que tenho no sql que é igual a 123456, acontece que se meter 1234567 entra na mesma e nao devia entrar. o 1234567 corresponde a '&%$#"! ' codificada.

Perceberam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar `%` para indicar que não te importa o que vem depois dele.
Observação: Para usar este operador você precisa usar `like`

Exemplos:
Buscar todas as linhas onde `campo` começa com `1234`

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo like '1234%'
```

Buscar todas as linhas onde `campo` contém `2345`

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo like '%2345%'
```

Buscar todas as linhas onde `campo` termina com `456`

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo like '%456'
```

Para autenticar usuário e senha, o correto é pegar a senha digitada pelo usuário, aplicar a criptografia nesta senha e comparar o resultado com a criptografia que já está salva no banco.

Comment: pois mas se tiver um espaço '123456  'no login ele entra e a pass é '123456'

Comment: @user2964140 Selects de autenticação de usuário e senha no banco de dados devem comparar se a senha digitada é EXATAMENTE IGUAL a senha guardada no banco, você não deve desconsiderar espaços nem nada do tipo... Talvez a sua pergunta deveria ser feita de outra maneira...

Comment: pois mas a senha é cifrada e pode conter espaços

Comment: @user2964140 Você deve pegar a senha digitada pelo usuário, aplicar a mesma criptografia nesta senha e comparar se o resultado é EXATAMENTE IGUAL ao que está no banco, desta maneira você não vai precisar desconsiderar nada, é apenas uma comparação exata.

Comment: sim já resolvi do problema com like 'asfdaf%'

Comment: @user2964140 Se esta resposta te ajudou, marque ela como resposta da sua pergunta por favor.

Comment: já esta marcada

Answer (score 2):

Faça a comparação do valor com a coluna utilizando `trim()` ou suas variantes(`ltrim()` e `rtrim()`).

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE trim(campo) = trim(valor)
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM UTILIZADORES where EMAIL ='nuno@nuno1.pt' AND PASSWORD =LTRIM('123456  ') na bd o campo so tem 123456

Comment: a  questao é que a base de dados pode ter tbm espaços em branco no genero '123456 8' ou ate mesmo um espaço....por isso o trim não resulta

Comment: No caso do valor `'123456'` comparado com o valor da base `'12345 '` o trim() resolve, agora `'12345 6'` não muito o que fazer.

Comment: a questão é que tenho um pass encritptada com o xor 23 ...123456 corresponde a isto '&%$#"!'  acontece que se meter no login 1234567 ele entra na mesa pois o 7 é um espaço e não devia de entrar, acontece é que tbm pode ter espaços  a palavra pass. Da mesma forma se a pass for '&%$#"!   '   e meter 123456 e entra tbm e não devia de entrar pois o caracteres nao sao iguais

Comment: @user2964140, edite sua pergunta e adicione esses detalhes pode ficar mais facil para outras pessoas responderem, coloca a tag do SQLServer também.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar que os valores com espaço no final retornem, você pode fazer uso da função `REPLACE`.

```
select * 
from TABELA
where replace(COLUNA, ' ', '_') = replace('123456', ' ', '_')
```

Segue exemplo no [rextester](http://rextester.com/BOFB29041)